# Date convention for holiday C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the business day using c#. I wonder if there is a way to find US holiday or should I just write a function to determine whether the date is holiday?

```
public bool isHoliday(DateTime date)
{
//holiday input 
}
```

Comment: If you ask 100 Americans for a list of holidays in the US, you'll get 100 different answers.  You'll need to define what constitutes a holiday for your app.

Comment: Depending on your institution, not all holidays are recognized.  So, you would probably need to explicitly define them.

Comment: This site offers a service and an API for this. I don't know how good they are and I am not affiliated with them. It is just the result of a search http://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/

Comment: I think you'll have to write a function therefor.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about defining what a holiday is.

Comment: @NeilN  My goal is to count the different holiday for different institutions. for example, if you are tagged as a university student, it would show the holiday for university students

Comment: Even for universities, the holidays can be vastly different.  Some might observe presidents day, others don't.

Comment: @NeilN  I think that is the hard part. altogether it is more than I expected , In my opinion the Dayan given a very good answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of this example:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11666/Dynamic-Holiday-Date-Calculator

The solution provided in that link:

> We decided that it would be ideal to store all of the rules for all of
>   the different holidays in an XML file, and then write a class that
>   could interpret those rules and calculate the correct date for each
>   holiday. To do this we had to separate out the holidays into different
>   types which were calculated similarly to each other. Below are the
>   different types of holidays that we dealt with and a sample XML
>   configuration for each:

```
<Holiday name="Groundhog Day">
    <Month>2</Month>
    <Day>2</Day>
</Holiday>

<Holiday name="Tax Day">
    <WeekdayOnOrAfter>
        <Month>4</Month>
        <Day>15</Day>
    </WeekdayOnOrAfter>
</Holiday>
```

The code is too much to post here, but this should solve your problem. Make use of that code  and modify to your needs.

Comment: In my understanding,it could fit for different institutions. am I right?

Comment: @galaxyan Yeah definitively. Read over the post by `Jay Muntz` in that link I provided. He goes into detail on how he solved the problem. Hope this helps you.

Comment: With the XML is not possible to represent all logic. For example fallback on a workday is the public holiday on weekend. You can use this library for calculation it supports the fallbacks to. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nager.Date

Answer (score 2):

This is a very primitive example of how you can store a table of US holidays for holidays with absolute dates. Labor Day and Columbus Day will require a little imagination as they are variable dates.

```
class VariableHoliday
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public bool IsOnDate(DateTime date)
    {
         //logic to detect the variable dates goes here!
    }
}

static readonly Dictionary<DateTime, string> m_Holidays = new Dictionary<DateTime,string>
{
    { new DateTime(1,1,1), "New Years Day" },
    { new DateTime(1,7,4), "Independence Day" },
    { new DateTime(1,7,4), "Independence Day" },
    /*FILL OUT ALL OF THE HOLIDAYS YOU WANT TO OBSERVE*/
};

static List<VariableHolidays> m_VariableHolidays = new List<VariableHolidays>();

public bool isHoliday(DateTime date)
{
    bool isHoliday = m_Holidays.HasKey(new DateTime(1, date.Month, date.Day));

    if(!isHoliday)
        m_VariableHolidays.Any(p => p.IsOnDate(date));
}

public string getHolidayName(DateTime date)
{
    if(m_Holidays.HasKey())
        return m_Holidays[new DateTime(1, date.Month, date.Day)];
    else
    {
        var holiday = m_VariableHolidays.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsOnDate(date));
        if(holiday != null) return holiday.Name
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Date is not a holiday");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.DayOfWeek to determine if it's a weekend or a weekday, but there's no inbuilt was to determine if it's a public holiday or not, if that's what you're asking.

See [DateTime.DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

My company uses a SQL table for all dates that are a holiday for the company, so this would be a simple single SELECT (or stored procedure). Then someone has to maintain that table. If it's just you, hard-coding would be pretty equivalent.

One major alternative is to scrape a website that lists public holidays. I assume you'd only want federal holidays, so excluding Valentine's Day for example. Depending on what your application is doing with it, you may need to be able to diverge from the standard list, which is where this falls down.

However you do it, I would suggest checking your method against sources including:

- http://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/us/
- http://archive.opm.gov/Operating_Status_Schedules/fedhol/2014.asp
- http://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/snow-dismissal-procedures/federal-holidays/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_holidays_in_the_United_States

Just to make sure you have what you want.